# How to save only the german data in my sql table?

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I save a lot of data from an xml file into a sql database. Some time ago the structure of the XML file has been changed. Now there is one data record for language "de" and one record for language "en". Since the structure has changed there are some errors of double return.

This is my new structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Results>
<SearchResult Language="de"><RouteID>28338</RouteID>..............
<SearchResult Language="en"><RouteID>28338</RouteID>..............
<SearchResult Language="de"><RouteID>28396</RouteID>..............
<SearchResult Language="en"><RouteID>28396</RouteID>..............
```

I only want to read from the german records via my php-xml-parser. Your help is really appreciated!

My code:

```
<?php    
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
/**
* Parser Class
*/
class Parser
{
var $dbo;
var $partner;

function __construct($dbo, $parser, $id) {
    $this->dbo = $dbo;
    $this->partner = new stdClass();
    $this->partner->name = $parser;
    $this->partner->id = $id;
}

function go() {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // creating parser object
    $xml_parser = xml_parser_create('UTF-8');

    // set encoding to UTF-8
    xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser,
            XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING,
            'UTF-8');

    // initializing the handler class
    $handler = new XMLHandlerClass(
            $this->dbo,
            $this->partner);

    // setting up the handlers
    xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser,
            array($handler, 'startElement'),
            array($handler, 'endElement'));
    xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser,
            array($handler, 'contents'));

    // path to the xml file
    $file = JPATH_SITE.DS.'tmp'.DS.'routes.xml';

    // open the file to read
    if (!($fp = fopen($file, "r"))) {
        die('konnte xml nicht öffnen');
        return false;
    }

    // read line after line from the xml file
    $data = null;
    while ($data = fgets($fp, 100000)) {
        if (!xml_parse($xml_parser, $data, feof($fp))) {
            die(sprintf("XML error: %s at line %d",
                xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($xml_parser)),
                xml_get_current_line_number($xml_parser)));
        }
    }

    // free the xml parser
    xml_parser_free($xml_parser);

    // every thing fine?
    return true;
    }
    }

 /**
* XML Handler Class
*/
class XMLHandlerClass
{
var $dbo;
var $partner;

var $element;

var $saveCounter = 0;
var $clearCounter = 0;

var $cabintype;
var $counterPrice = 0;

var $counterRoute = 0;

var $item;

var $api;

function __construct($dbo, $partner) {

    // save params
    $this->dbo = $dbo;
    $this->partner = $partner;

    // include api
    include_once JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR
            .DS.'api'.DS.'KreuzfahrtenAPI.php';

    // initialize api
    $this->api = new KreuzfahrtenAPI($this->dbo,
            $this->partner->name,
            $this->partner->id);
}

function startElement($parser, $name, $attrs) {
    // don't give up
    set_time_limit(120);

    // get the name
    $this->element = strtolower($name);

    // bevor das speichern der tripps beginnt,
    // aber eigentlich schon die routen informationen da sind
    // soll die dauer noch um 1 gekürzt werden
    if ($this->element == "listoftrips") {
        $this->item['dauer'] -= 1;
    }
}

function endElement($parser, $name) {

    // don't give up
    set_time_limit(120);

    // get the name
    $name = strtolower($name);

    // counter hochzählen
    switch ($name) {
        case "port":
            $this->counterRoute++;
            break;
        case "cabin":
            $this->counterPrice++;
            break;
        case "trip":
            $this->saveCounter++;
            $this->save();
            break;
        case "route":
            $this->clearCounter++;
            $this->clear();
            break;
    }
}

function contents($parser, $data) {

    // remove quots
    $data = $this->reEn($data);

    // assign the $data by the $this->element
    switch ($this->element) {
        case "routeid":
            $this->item['routeid'] .= $data;
            break;
        case "name":
            $this->item['titel'] .= $data;
            break;
        case "duration":
            $this->item['dauer'] .= $data;
            break;
        case "port":
            if ($this->counterRoute != 0 && $this->counterRoute != 1) {
                $this->item['route'][$this->counterRoute-2] .= $data;
            }
            break;
        case "priceoverview":
            if ($data == "Einzel") break;
            switch ($data) {
                case "bestinsidecabinprice":
                    $this->cabintype = "Innenkabine";
                    break;
                case "bestoutsidecabinprice":
                    $this->cabintype = "Außenkabine";
                    break;
                case "bestsuitecabinprice":
                    $this->cabintype = "Suite";
                    break;
                case "bestbalconycabinprice":
                    $this->cabintype = "Balkonkabine";
                    break;
                default:
                    die('Kein passender Kabinentyp '.$data);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case "bestprice":
            $cabinetype = $this->cabintype;
            $this->item['prices'][$cabinetype][$this->counterPrice] .= str_replace(',', '.', $data);
            unset($cabinetype);
            break;
        case "tripbegins":
            $this->item['beginn'] .= $data;
            break;
        case "tripends":
            $this->item['ende'] .= $data;
            break;
        case "destinationname":
            $this->item['zielgebiet'] .= $data;
            break;
        case "shipname":
            $this->item['schiff'] .= $data;
            break;
    }
}

function reEn($subject) {
    $toDel = array (
        '"',
        "'"
    );
    $toRe = array(
        '',
        ''
    );
    $subject = str_replace($toDel, $toRe, $subject);
    return $subject;
}

function clear($error = false) {
    if ($error) {
        $title = "ERROR:Clear";
        $description = "ITEM:\n"
            .$this->api->implodeItem($this->item);
        $this->api->setErrorMsg($title,$description);
    }

    $this->element = null;
    $this->item = null;
    $this->cabintype = null;
    $this->counterPrice = 0;
    $this->counterRoute = 0;
}

function save() {
    // neues zeitlimit setzen
    set_time_limit(120);

    // prüfe ob alle daten vorhanden sind
    if (empty($this->item['titel'])
            || empty($this->item['routeid'])
            || empty($this->item['dauer'])
            || !is_array($this->item['route'])
            || !is_array($this->item['prices'])
            || empty($this->item['beginn'])
            || empty($this->item['ende'])
            || empty($this->item['zielgebiet'])
            || empty($this->item['schiff'])
                    ) {
        $this->clear(TRUE);
        return false;
    } else {
        // daten für api vorbereiten

        // -- url
        $this->item['url'] = "www.domain.com/?fuseaction=product.showroute="
                .$this->item['routeid']
                ."&ID=XXX";
        // -- datum
        $this->item['beginn'] = $this->api->convertDate(
                explode('.', $this->item['beginn'])
        );
        $this->item['ende'] = $this->api->convertDate(
                explode('.', $this->item['ende'])
        );
        // reise mit der api speichern
        $this->api->save($this->item);

        // nicht mehr nötige daten löschen
        unset($this->item['beginn'],
                $this->item['ende'],
                $this->item['prices']);
    }
}
}
?>
```

Errors: 
In some records I get 3 to 4 different names

```
schiff = CamargueModiglianiModigliani
zielgebiet = RhoneSaôneRheinRhine
routeid = 282992829928338
```

I think the language attribute must be the connection between this...

Comment: I can't make head nor tail of that, but instead of selecting all SearchResults just select Results/SearchResult[@Language="de"]

Comment: Thanks, but how do I code this exactly?

Comment: @user2482128: Xpath. Part of SimpleXML or DOMDocument. Your code looks a bit akward using XML_Parser here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just read every record and only consider the ones who have 'Language="de"'?

EDIT :

In the save method, add the following condition in the "if empty" part :

```
|| $this->item['Language'] != "de"
```

This will make the records who are not in the German language be cleared as if they were not suitable.

Comment: I´d really like to, but don´t know how... This is what I´m asking for!

Answer (score 0):

use `simplexml`and `xpath` to select de-entries only:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("datei.xml");
$de = $xml->xpath("//SearchResult[@Language = 'de']");
```

Now, `$de` contains an array with all nodes with `Language = "de"`. You can iterate and store the values to your DB.

If you showed a more complete and valid snippet of your XML, we could give you more specific support.